# Best practice for google TagManager and Android

Tags: android, google-analytics-firebase

In all code examples I find online it looks something like:

```
pending.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder) {
        ...
        startMainActivity();
    }
}, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

without any explanation of what startMainActivity() do. By the name it seem to start a new activity. Is it the best practice to start a new activity?
Or is it OK to update the current activity from here.

I believe there can be problems if you update the same activity because the callback is not synchronized and if you do fragment transactions there might be state loss.
Right now our code base does not start a new activity, so I'd like to know if I should rewrite it or not.

So the question again: *is it best practice to start a new activity?*

Comment: It is depends on your app flow , when you want to startActivity.

Comment: I updated the question Ishrat. What I wonder if I should start a new activity or uptdate the current activity.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason for starting main activity here is that before onResult is called the container is not loaded or usable. Starting the main activity in onResult is simple way to ensure that user, or the app itself does not initiate anything that might require access to the container before the container is loaded. Depending on your app logic, there may be other ways.